# PHP: Get username from session

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I'm not very good at PHP and I have a little problem. I've been playing around with [this script](http://www.emirplicanic.com/php/simple-phpmysql-authentication-class).

And I can't for the life of me figure out how to echo the username of a logged in user.
I tried to print all the information of the session like this:

```
var_dump($_SESSION)
```

but I just got the hashed password and the userlevel int.

Can someone maybe help me here? I just want to be able to echo the username.

Comment: The script you linked to does't save the username in as a session variable. If you want that, you have to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to store the username in the session for it to be available on another page load, currently the script only stores these values in the session;

```
 $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $row[$this->pass_column];
 $_SESSION['userlevel'] = $row[$this->user_level];
```

What you have to do is add the `$username` to the session that is passed into the `login` function, like below;

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

The username will now be stored in the session with the key username.

To be able to use it on another page, make sure that before attempting to use it you initiate the session by calling the function `session_start()`.

Comment: Wow, that was a really fast answer. This worked perfectly! Thank you very much.

Comment: @PatricF No problem if it helped you consider accepting the answer as it will help others in the future

Answer (score 1):

Basically, just write it inside like

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'];
```

or

```
 echo $_SESSION['password'];
```

---

### A brief explanation of how sessions work.

**first** you start the session and assign any value to a session ex:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'john';
```

then echoing works like:

```
echo $_SESSION['username']; // will echo out 'jonh'
```

**note** `session_start()` must be shared in-between the pages you want to use the session

Comment: It it does not give you anything, the you have not assigned a session yet

Comment: @PatricF: when responding to answers, you need to give them something to work with. For example, you could link to an external copy of your script as it now stands. Otherwise, how is this answerer meant to respond?

Answer (score 0):

You have session_start(); on top ?

Comment: Yes I have that on top. I get the information from the session, there's just no information on the username..

Comment: so if you do the following:
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'Test';
echo $_SESSION['username'];

it will return nothing ?

Answer (score 0):

In the login function you should write the username to the session after a successful login.

```
//instantiate if needed
include("class.login.php");
$log = new logmein();
$log->encrypt = true; //set encryption
if($_REQUEST['action'] == "login"){
    if($log->login("logon", $_REQUEST['username'], $_REQUEST['password']) == true){
         //do something on successful login
         $_SESSION['username'] = $_REQUEST['username'];
    }else{
         //do something on FAILED login
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include('db.php');
session_start();
$name=$_POST['name'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
echo $sql="SELECT * FROM register WHERE (name='$name' OR email='$name') AND password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows > 0)
 {
    $_SESSION['user']=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    $row = $_SESSION['user'];
    $role = $row['role'];

            if($role == 1)
            {
                header('location:usermanagement.php');
            }
            else{
                header('location:user.php');
            }

}
else
 {

    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
    header('location:login.php');
}
$conn->close();
?>
```