# how to verify username and password for java page

Tags: php, authentication, session

I have created a PHP page for two clients, same data same everything, they are only separated by their file path in the server and MySQL tables.

Here is the case, I have a welcome.php file which is required by all pages to know if there exists already an active logged-in session and if not, the user is redirected to the login.php page.

Here is the code I have in the login.php:

```
<?php
 // Initialize the session
// This sends a persistent cookie that lasts a day.
session_start([
'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
]);

// If session variable is not set it will redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){
header("location: /JB104/login.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

This code works just as wanted, because it confirms if there exists a login session and shows the user their requested page, and if not, the user is redirected to the login page.

Here is the issue:

I just observed that if I am in the page of one client, let's say the client A has this path: xxxxx.com/AAA/home.php and I change to let's say xxxxx.com/BBB/home.php, the page doesn't control login parameters, it switches to the new page with the initial credentials during the first login.

How can I create a verification between these two login credentials, so that user AAA cannot access user BBB by first login into xxxxx.com/AAA/home.php and then changing the url to xxxxx.com/BBB/home.php?

Also there exist different tables for the login credentials for each user.

Comment: Your question title talks about a "java page". There is no mention of Java anywhere else in your question. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the username of session and then redirect accordingly , in your user's php file where it renders home.php of each user, just check the request path or obtain the user for which page is being accessed and then try to cross check it with the username from session variable, if it fails just exit or redirect to another proper page
You can also readirect from login page,point is just checking username isnt enough,do processing on your $_SESSION['username'] and redirect or prevent access from comparing it

Comment: thanks Mathur , but please can you kindly provide me some guide dumb come , so at-least i know how to combine the verifications . thanks once again

Comment: You need to prevent access by checking the sessions's set username check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657968/php-get-username-from-session) Please upvote if this helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is related to the session identification. Probably your application does not differentiate the sessions between the different projects.

I experienced a similar problem in [Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/) and the cause was that the projects were configured to the same session name, i.e., they had the same value for the session name.